# Stroked ring shape with width

Tags: android, shapes

I have custom progress bar shape... And I want background(which is filled with gray) to make stroked, iner and outer stroke with 9dp gap between them... 
It seems that I can't get it to work.

This is original XML of progress bar inner circle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="60dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="9dp"
            android:useLevel="true">


        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/light_gray"
            android:endColor="@color/light_gray"
            android:type="sweep" />

        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This is screenshot of output:
[image: Progress Bar]

*And one question more(I dont want to open another question):
-Can I make this orange end to be oval(rounded) somehow? Like on most progress bars? 
**XML is same like top one, just different color.***

**EDIT**: It may help, I use progress bar component with custom background.

**EDIT2**: I accomplished by setting circle radius on 60 and thicknesson 1dp, and creating another ProgressBar component with another background with 69 radius and 1dp thickness.

I got what I need in design, this is not good approach. Can I get help on second question?

Comment: for your 2nd question change android:shape="oval"

Comment: @Madhur, "oval" isn't right answer. Because I need ring shape. :/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code for creating progress bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:endColor="#00FF00"
            android:angle="0"
            />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

and for there look and feel and for more info please refer https://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/customization-of-spinner-progress/

Comment: is it useful for you ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but don't, because I already have this progress bar with curved text and some stuff in it. And I need this type because it ticks 60seconds, one by one. Just would like to have stroked path in it. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a custom view. With this approach you can draw a ring with rounded caps:

```
int border = 4; // This value is in PX!
RectF rect = new RectF();
Paint paint = new Paint();
int radius = getMeasuredWidth() - border/2;

rect.set(border/2, border/2, radius, radius);
paint.setStrokeWidth(border);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(Color.Orange);
canvas.drawArc(rect, -90, 360, true, paint);
```

Then you can draw another circle inside or another ring as background. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, can I do it with shapes, because don't know how to do it with canvas like this. Because i have progress bar component with custom background. :)